# Java/LibGDX - Track collected items from room to room

Tags: java, libgdx, platform, inventory

I am writing a game based on Jet Set Willy for a personal project. As you will know, the character can move from room to room, collecting items as he goes.

I am using LibGDX and the Tiled Map editor.

I currently load my items based on Object Tiles in my map, which are on a layer called 'Items', as per below:

```
public void loadItems() {
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //create all Items
    for(MapObject object : map.getLayers().get(4).getObjects().getByType(RectangleMapObject.class)){
        Rectangle rect = ((RectangleMapObject) object).getRectangle();
        //new Item(screen, object);
        items.add(new Item(this, object, (rect.getX() + rect.getWidth() / 2) / Engine.PPM, (rect.getY() + rect.getHeight() / 2) / Engine.PPM));
    }
}
```

The items are stored in an Array on my Playscreen as follows:

```
public static Array<Item> items;
```

When the items are collected, I simply remove them from the screen.

To switch rooms I essentially load a new map, fetch that level's Items etc. The problem is, that if I move back to the original room I need to fetch the items again, which draws them all again.

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/**
 * Load the next Level
 */
public void changeMap(int roomNumber, float x, float y) {
    map.dispose();
    loadMap(roomNumber);


    this.current_level = roomNumber;

    renderer.getMap().dispose(); //dispose the old map
    renderer.setMap(map); //set the map in your renderer

    world = new World(new Vector2(0,-4 ), true);
    world.setContactListener(new WorldContactListener());

    creator = new B2WorldCreator(this);
    loadItems();

    //Reposition Player
    player = new Player(world, this, x * Engine.TILE_WIDTH, y * Engine.TILE_HEIGHT);
}
```

My Item class is as follows:

```
public class Item extends Sprite {

protected World world;
protected PlayScreen screen;

private float stateTime;
protected TiledMap map;
protected MapObject object;

private Animation animation;
private Array<TextureRegion> frames;
private boolean setToDestroy;
private boolean destroyed;
float angle;
public Body b2body;

FixtureDef fdef;

private Texture tex;
private Texture blank_texture;
private int item_number;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/**
 * Constructor
 * @param screen
 * @param object
 * @param x
 * @param y
 */
public Item(PlayScreen screen, MapObject object, float x, float y){
    this.world = screen.getWorld();
    this.screen = screen;
    this.map = screen.getMap();
    //this.item_number = item_number;

    setPosition(x, y);

    Random rn = new Random();
    int max = 2;
    int min = 1;
    int random = rn.nextInt(5) + 1;

    tex = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("sprites/item" + random + ".png"));

    frames = new Array<TextureRegion>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        frames.add(new TextureRegion(tex, i * 16, 0, 16, 16));
    }

    animation = new Animation(0.1f, frames);

    blank_texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("sprites/blank_item.png"));

    setBounds(getX(), getY(), 15 / Engine.PPM, 15 / Engine.PPM);
    setToDestroy = false;
    destroyed = false;
    angle = 0;

    stateTime = 0;

    define_item();
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/**
 *Define the Box2D body for the item
 */
public void define_item() {


    BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
    bdef.position.set(getX(), getY());
    bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
    b2body = world.createBody(bdef);

    fdef = new FixtureDef();
    fdef.filter.categoryBits = Engine.ITEM_BIT;
    fdef.filter.maskBits = Engine.PLAYER_BIT;

    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    shape.setAsBox(7 / Engine.PPM, 7 / Engine.PPM);

    fdef.shape = shape;

    b2body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData(this);
    b2body.setGravityScale(0);
    b2body.setActive(true);
}


public void redefineItem() {

    Gdx.app.log("redefineItem", "Item");

    Vector2 position = b2body.getPosition();
    world.destroyBody(b2body);

    BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
    bdef.position.set(position);
    bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
    b2body = world.createBody(bdef);

    fdef = new FixtureDef();
    fdef.filter.categoryBits = Engine.ITEM_BIT;
    fdef.filter.maskBits = Engine.PLAYER_BIT;

    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    shape.setAsBox(7 / Engine.PPM, 7 / Engine.PPM);

    fdef.shape = shape;

    b2body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData(this);
    b2body.setGravityScale(0);
    b2body.setActive(true);
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/**
 * Draw Method
 * @param batch
 */
@Override
public void draw(Batch batch) {
    if(!destroyed) {
        super.draw(batch);
    }
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/**
 * Update the Items
 * @param dt
 */
public void update(float dt){

    setRegion(getFrame(dt));
    stateTime += dt;

    if(setToDestroy && !destroyed){
        world.destroyBody(b2body);
        destroyed = true;
        setRegion(blank_texture);
        stateTime = 0;
    }
    else if(!destroyed) {
        setRegion(animation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true));
        setPosition(b2body.getPosition().x - getWidth() / 2, b2body.getPosition().y - getHeight() / 2);
    }
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/**
 * Get the Texture
 * @param dt
 * @return
 */
public TextureRegion getFrame(float dt){
    TextureRegion region;
    region = animation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
    return region;
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/**
 * Item has been collected
 * @param player
 */
public void collected(Player player) {
    if(Engine.bPlaySounds) {
        Sound sound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("audio/sounds/collect_item.wav"));
        sound.play(1.0f);
    }

    //Change the Category Bit, so that it is no longer collidable
    fdef.filter.categoryBits = Engine.COLLECTED_BIT;
    this.setToDestroy = true;

    Gdx.app.log("Collected Item ", "" + this.item_number + " from room " + screen.getCurrentLevel() );

    //Increment the counter on the HUD
    screen.incrementItemCounter();
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/**
 * Set the category Filter
 * @param filterBit
 */
public void setCategoryFilter(short filterBit){
    Filter filter = new Filter();
    filter.categoryBits = filterBit;
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/**
 * Get the Tilemap cell
 * @return
 */
public TiledMapTileLayer.Cell getCell(){
    TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(0);
    return layer.getCell((int)(b2body.getPosition().x * Engine.PPM / 16), (int)(b2body.getPosition().y * Engine.PPM / 16));
}
```

}

I'd like to store each item I collect in some kind of array, which includes the room number, and the item's X/Y position. When I redraw the items, it will skip any of the items which are in the collected list. Problem is, I'm not sure how to achieve this in Java.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might achieve this?

Regards

James

Comment: Depending on the number of levels, the items, and data you want to save, libGDX's Preferences may be the easiest. Guess it depends on your definition of "small game state saves", and/or if you can find a clever way to maybe encode your roomItemStates in a string or numeric representation - https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking it could be a simple array [room_number, item_number]. When I load the items I could compare perhaps against this array and only render the ones which are not in the collected array. It only needs to remember them whilst playing - I don't intend to have any game saves etc. What do you think?

Comment: Ah, OK. I misunderstood. I thought you were looking for some kind of persistence. If it is only in memory, then that is more straightforward. A hashmap may be easiest, where the key is the room number, and the value would be however you want to store your collected items - list, array, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you can do this. Here's one suggestion:

Store all your rooms' item lists in a map object and read from the map in `loadItems()` if appropriate. Also, I would avoid the use of `static` unless it is really necessary--that can easily lead to sneaky bugs if you're still a bit new to Java, and they aren't usually good object-oriented practice.

```
private final IntMap<Array<Item>> roomsToItems = new IntMap();
private Array<Item> items;

//...

public void loadItems(int roomNumber) {
    items = roomsToItems.get(roomNumber); //get this room's previous list if it exists
    if (items == null) { //this room hasn't been loaded yet
        items = new Array<>();

        //TODO: Load the items into "items"

        //store the items list so it can be retrieved instead of loaded next time:
        roomsToItems.put(roomNumber, items);
    }
}
```

Then you can safely remove items from `items` and the list will reflect that the next time you enter the room.

Comment: You could also use Java's `HashMap<Integer, Array<Item>>`, but the LibGDX IntMap is better optimized for a game. It doesn't have to box the ints into Integer instances.

Comment: Thanks Tenfour04, that's a great idea. I'll have a crack at that for sure. Thanks again for taking the time.

Comment: This works perfectly in terms of re-drawing the sprites, but when they are re-loaded when re-entereing the room, they have all lost their Box2D bodies, and are therefore no longer collectable. I'll calling a method on the Item called redefineItem() which re-creates box2D bodies but it still doesn't work. Any ideas how I might resolve this?

Comment: Without knowing your whole structure I can only guess. Are you creating a new world when changing rooms? If so, you need to pass the new world into your redefineItem() method and assign it accordingly.

Comment: Hooray - finally nailed it Tenfour04. The update method on the Items class was not getting the correct world after the room had been built. So I passed the world through to Update(World world) and the Box2D bodies were correctly applied to the remaining items. Thanks for all your help, I had never used intMaps before and was unsure about using Final too. You have educated me a little bit more. Here is the result if you are interested: https://youtu.be/36cF6wdmOWQ